# PHP Prepared Statments - Can't Select Varchar Rows, No Problems Selecting Numeric Rows

Tags: c#, php, mysql, .net

Alright, I'm having a really oddball problem here. I'm trying to SELECT a row via PHP, but for some reason it just won't grab the row data! It's not having any problems with fetching numeric rows or anything.

**NOTE: I am sending the arguments via a C# WinForm, could this be a cause of the problem (collation or something)?**

```
$stmt_GetSalt = $con->prepare("SELECT Salt,Status FROM Accounts WHERE Email=?");
$stmt_GetSalt->bind_param("s", $email);
$stmt_GetSalt->execute();
$stmt_GetSalt->bind_result($salt, $status);
$stmt_GetSalt->fetch();
$stmt_GetSalt->close();
```

Status is an `int`, but has no problem returning a value. Salt is a `varchar` but no data is being returned. What's going on here?

**EDIT: XML Representation of data in the table.**

`<table name="Accounts">
            <column name="Email">test@testmail.test3</column>
            <column name="Password">65T6ANoLeSrBA</column>
            <column name="Salt">65fe93d93e283f002beaca712fd178c6</column>
            <column name="PIN">81dc9bdb52d04dc20036dbd8313ed055</column>
            <column name="Status">0</column>
            <column name="ID">5</column>
</table>`

**EDIT 2:** Fixed the problem. I was instantiating `$email` AFTER binding the params. So the statement was trying to bind a parameter that did not yet exist. I shouldn't code late at night.

Comment: What is in the table, not what are you having trouble getting out. What is in the table, not what is supposed to be in table

Comment: [Here's a image of what's in the table](http://i.imgur.com/Rpb7k6g.png).

Comment: Post text sample in question. People dont want to click on a surprise here

Comment: @TiesonT. "Status" is being retrieved just fine, It's the other (varchar) rows like Salt, Password, Email.

Comment: I'm seriously convinced it has something to do with the collation of the database. Does MySQL and .NET use different text formatting?

Comment: If the MySQL instance is hosted on a *nix server, it's possible.

Comment: You didn't post the part of the script that does something with the fetched record. Exactly how do you come to the conclusion that the varchar column hasn't been fetched properly?

Comment: @TiesonT. It is running on Linux, doesn't mention which distro though. Does anyone happen to know what sort of text formatting .NET uses?

Comment: @VolkerK I've tried to `echo();` various different varchar rows, and none have worked. The ints do though.

Comment: And the client was always your WinForms application or did you also try it with a webbrowser?

Comment: I would suspect something other than character encoding. I've pulled varchar text from a MySQL instance into an ASP.NET MVC app without needing to re-encode it.

Comment: I can't find anything yet about problematic varchar bindings

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce the problem

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'localonly', 'localonly', 'test');
setup($mysqli);
var_export( foo($mysqli, 'test@testmail.test3') );

function foo($con, $email) {
    $stmt_GetSalt = $con->prepare("SELECT Salt,Status FROM soFoo WHERE Email=?");
    $stmt_GetSalt->bind_param("s", $email);
    $stmt_GetSalt->execute();
    $stmt_GetSalt->bind_result($salt, $status);
    $stmt_GetSalt->fetch();
    $stmt_GetSalt->close();
    return array('salt'=>$salt, 'status'=>$status);
}

function setup($mysqli) {
    $mysqli->query('
        CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE soFoo (
            Salt varchar(32),
            Status int,
            email varchar(32)
        )
    ');

    $mysqli->query("
        INSERT INTO soFoo (Salt,Status,email) VALUES
        ('65fe93d93e283f002beaca712fd178c6', 0, 'test@testmail.test3')
    ");
}
```

prints

```
array (
  'salt' => '65fe93d93e283f002beaca712fd178c6',
  'status' => 0,
)
```

as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem. I was instantiating $email AFTER binding the parameters. So the statement was trying to bind a parameter that did not yet exist. I shouldn't code late at night.

Comment: No offense but that doesn't sound like the actual problem/solution. a) this wouldn't explain why you _could_ fetch one column but not the other and b) first binding the variable and then assigning the value works, no problem

Comment: It worked after I put `$email = $_POST["email"];` before the statement.

Comment: so you mean you didn't assign _any_ value to $mail prior to execute(). Still doesn't explain how you could fetch the field `status`, but anyway...

Comment: Yeah, I don't know. I'm honestly as confused as you are lol.